# Defining calculated constants in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, constants

I'm trying to make it so that when a user creates my UIView subclass, MyView, he can pass an integer, and then some calculations are done on this integer and a constant variable is set to the integer's new calculated value. What's the best practice for setting something like this up?

I know #define exists (although I don't know how'd you do calculations) and I know there is a const keyword, but I've never used these. I've accomplished stuff like this in the past with properties but I know that's not correct.

Answer (score 2):

`#define` is simply a redefinition in your code. Does not do anything useful. If I understand you correctly, you might want to define a custom constructor for your `UIView` subclass which accepts the desired parameter.

```
- (instancetype)initWithParam:(NSInteger)someInteger;
```

And since you are doing a calculation based on the input parameter, it is not actually a constant, so you just might want to write a method for this.

```
- (NSInteger)someCalculatedProperty;
```

Comment: I'll use an example to help clarify. I pass a param of int i = 1 to my view's constructor. We'll call my "constant" x. In the constructor the view says, ok, x = i + 5; Once x is set it should not be changed, and in that sense it is constant, and this value will be used often.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply define it like this:

```
integer_t const x= 10;
```

Also you may try like this:

```
#define x 10
```

> although I don't know how'd you do calculations

I am not sure what you mean by calculation but if you are trying to do some calculation in the constant itself *then avoid that*. As then it would  **not** be a constant.